# Can't mount hard drive; "an operation is already pending"

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I am trying to pull files from an internal hard drive on a laptop that I believe is completely full. Windows will not start in regular mode and does not offer the safe mode option. I have tried to launch the startup repair mode but it ends in a blue screen with "sunlight" and my cursor.

[image: screen shown when I try startup repair]

I then booted from a Live Ubuntu DVD and ran "TRY Ubuntu".  When I try to access the hard drive from LINUX it shows an error message: "Unable to access 481 GB Volume" and then shows the following error code:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at/media/ubuntu/6EEECE59EECE18EB:
Command-line 'mount-t"nfts"-o
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=000" "/dev/sda2" "/media/ubuntu/6EEECE59EECE18EB"' exited with non-zero exit status 13:ntfs_attr_pread frailed:Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap:Input/output error
NTFS either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot int windows twice.  The useage of the /f parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Pease see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.
```

[image: error message]

I am not savvy enough to know where or how to input the code to allow me read-only access to the drive (I just need to copy files to an external device and then will install ubuntu permanently and format the drive).  Any advice will be most appreciated but please treat me like a 4 year old and walk me through the steps, if possible!

Thank you in advance to whomever responds!

Comment: could you boot into a the Ubuntu LiveCD and open a terminal and type `sudo gparted` and tell me the different partitions and file systems and if they show a boot flag... such as `/dev/sda1/ FS= ext4 with boot flag` don't worry this will make more sense when  you launch the program and mine is only an example .. the file system most likely is ntfs. and add the results to your question